# Routing for partial view not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a route defined for my Partial View like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ListInventory",
    "Inventory/List/{Id}/{code}",
    new { controller = "Inventory", action = "ListItems" },
    new[] { "TYP.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

I'm using the jQuery load method to get the HTML from this partial view

```
$(".main").empty()
   .load("@Url.Action("ListItems", "Inventory", new { Id = Model.Id, code = Model.Code })")
```

Url.Action renders the url correctly according to my route as:

```
/Inventory/List/1/ABC
```

But I just get a 404 error from that URL. If I navigate directly to

```
/Inventory/ListItems?Id=1&code=ABC
```

it works though. So the route is kind of being recognized. If I remove the route entirely from the RouteConfig.cs file, then `Url.Action()` renders my URL as:

```
/Inventory/ListItems?Id=1&amp;code=ABC
```

But in this case, the `&amp;` causes an issue on my `code` query string value.

What can I do here to get this partial view working correctly?

Comment: Is this a mistake? `$(".main").empty()
   .load("@Url.Action("ListItems", "Inventory", new { Id = Model.Id, code = Model.Code })")` ? I see double quotes open after `.Action(` and before `@Url` which is actually makes character end!! Shouldn't it be like `$(".main").empty()
   .load('@Url.Action("ListItems", "Inventory", new { Id = Model.Id, code = Model.Code })')`?

Answer (score 0):

That is because in your route you specify the action to be remapped as **List** instead of **ListItems**. That means **/Inventory/ListItems** will no longer work instead use **/Inventory/List**.

Please refer to the code below:

Change this code:

```
@Url.Action("ListItems", "Inventory", new { Id = Model.Id, code = Model.Code })
```

To this code:

```
@Url.Action("List", "Inventory", new { Id = Model.Id, code = Model.Code })
```